# Necessity of calling Elem() method on pointer-receiver for struct reflection

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reflection

I have struct

```
type ChartOpts struct {
    Name              mypakage.MyType
    Repo              mypakage.MyType
}
```

on which I want to set a receiver for reflection.

```
func (chartOpts *ChartOpts) BindFlags() {
    fields := reflect.TypeOf(chartOpts)
    values := reflect.ValueOf(chartOpts)
    num := fields.NumField()
    fmt.Println(fields, values, num)
}
```

The above code panics

```
panic: reflect: NumField of non-struct type *app.ChartOpts
```

Why do I need to call the `Elem()` method to fix this?

```
func (chartOpts *ChartOpts) BindFlags() {
    fields := reflect.TypeOf(chartOpts)
    values := reflect.ValueOf(chartOpts)
    num := fields.Elem().NumField()
    fmt.Println(fields, values, num)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because type of `chartOpts` is `*ChartOpts`, a pointer to `ChartOpts` type. Pointers have no fields, only structs. Calling `Elem()` on its type descriptor will return a type descriptor that represents / describes `ChartOpts`, a struct type which does have fields.